# Porting from react with apollo to Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, apollo

I am working on a site with react, graphQL and apollo. I intend on moving everything to a Gatsby site, mainly because of SEO concerns

Should i use [Gatsby plugin apollo](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-apollo/), or the static Query method? I don't understand if this StaticQuery is only for data in the config file or can be used for an API in which a uri needs to be specified, and if I can, how do I input the uri

Any advice in the right direction is appreciated (whatever is simpler)

Thank you